# Unable to call a jQuery function on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am trying calling a jQuery function while clicking the save button. But i didn't get any response while clicking the button.

```html
<button type="button" id="save" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Save Expense</button>
```

```js
$('#save').on('click', function() {
  alert("test");
  var data = $('form').serialize();
  console.log("data" + data);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "saveExpense",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      alert("Success");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `$("save")` finds all the `<save>` elements in your document

Comment: <button type="button" id="save" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Save Expense</button>

Comment: Then you want `$("#save")`

Comment: yeah i tried that too .. not working

Comment: If your script appears before the part of the document that includes the button, it won't work. Put it in a "ready" handler or but the `<script>` block at the end of the `<body>`.

Comment: great that's working

Answer (score 0):

Create a click event like this , this will solve your problem.

```js
$(document).on('click','#save', function() {
      alert("test");
      var data = $('form').serialize();
      console.log("data" + data);
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "saveExpense",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
          alert("Success");
        }
      })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="save" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Save Expense</button>
```

Comment: How do you know that the element in question is dynamically added? If you assume it is you need to add an explanation to your code why you are doing it. Also as a side note it is important to mention that `document` should be the last choice as the closest static element is preferred instead for performance reasons. - Either way the issue seems solved by OP in comments on post, which had nothing to do with dynamic elements.

Comment: @Fran delegation is not just for dynamic elements; it can be used generally. However I do agree that an explanation of what the code here does and why it works would be a good idea.